# Disadvantages and limitations of ETags

Tags: apache, etag

`ETags`, as I read about, is one of the ways to implement the `Caching validation`. We are planning to implement this on our servers.  We have 2 apaches running.  I wanted to know if there are any limitations and disadvantages in using `ETags`.  If there are no such limitation, then why ain't it being used as a simple rule in configuring one's server(s)?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using cache validation means that the request will make a network call and hit the application, regardless. The application must take care of the ETag and decide if the former response is still valid or not. This, effectively, means that your application will build the whole response again just to calculate the ETag. This means that ETags will save you some bandwidth if your responses are heavy, but may not save you too much otherwise. If your responses *are* heavy, usually the first response is to gzip.

Comment: how much of a difference can it make??

Comment: Just wanted to add one point that it is not necessary to calculate ETag from response. One can use ETag revision numbers where it can be incremented when a server updates the response data.